# Is it possible to get a link?

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = textBox1.Text;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.google.com/search?q="+x+"&btnI");
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Simple code, but I don't want the program to go to the link of the Textbox1.text on youtube. I want the program to just give me the link of the search back and not to go there.

I want to put a word on the text box and when I press the button it should give me the link of youtube and not to go there (like my program does at the moment it goes to the youtube link).

Couldn't explain better. Hope you guys can understand what I wanna do.

Comment: You should look at the `WebClient`https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx class, so you can see the response code and body. Google probably uses a redirect which is handled by the browser. A `WebClient` will let you intercept it yourself.

Comment: @kariryzh if it is difficult to explain, just add a concrete example of what you want to do. For example, if I enter "stackoverflow" in Textbox1, what would you like to happen next?

Comment: @Wimmel like getting a youtube link for the song i wanna search for lets say i typed in the text box a name of the song and on the other hand i wanna get the link of the song and add in on variable so i can download the song.

Comment: Question isn't clear still, may be you would want to use their api (youtube)? All your code is doing right now is on button click, its starting the process (Browser) to the given url.

Comment: @kariryzh So if I enter "singing in the rain", you would like to get "www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1ZYhVpdXbQ"? This is the 4th search result for me, (the first three search results are wikipedia and imdb).

Comment: @Wimmel thats another problem i will fix later ^^ but all i wanna get is the url it self for now

Comment: @kariryzh I am just asking for an example

Comment: @Wimmel the example you said is exactly what i want to get like searching "let her go" and usually the first search is a youtube link so i wanna get "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBumgq5yVrA"

Comment: ok, then it looks to me that pasty has the right answer.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Comment: @Wimmel i get error every time i try to write his code here is the error:
"the type or namespace name "httpclient" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to retrieve the URL that is returned by google when the query is fired. One possibility would be to use the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class in order to retrieve the request and from it the requested URL from the [RequestMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) property:

```
var url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&btnI";
var http = new HttpClient();
var response = http.GetAsync(url);
Console.WriteLine(response.Result.RequestMessage.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);
```

The output is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
```